# How to get menus to stack left-to-right but not squash their contents

Tags: hover, css, html

Very new to CSS so forgive the noob question, but I am trying to figure out how to use CSS box model to create dropdown menus.

The menu headings need to flow left to right across the page according to their width.

The contents  of the dropdowns need to NOT be squashed to the width of the title: they should be as wide as the widest menu item.

My best guess is the following. (I have turned off some of the hover behaviour to make page inspection easier.)

```
<head>
<style>
body { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.dropdown { position: relative; }
.dropdown .title { display:inline-block; background:#eee; padding: 6px; }
.dropdown ul { border: 1px solid grey; background:white; position:absolute; top:14px; left:0px; list-style-type: none; padding:0;}
.dropdown li { width: auto; padding: 6px; }

._dropdown ul { display: none; visibility: invisible; }
._dropdown .title:hover { background-color: #333; color:white; }
._dropdown .title:hover > ul { display: block; }
.dropdown li:hover { background-color: #def; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="title">Menu title
        <ul><li><a href=#>Unit 1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Unit 2</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Unit 3 A really long one</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="title">Menu title
        <ul><li><a href=#>Unit 1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Unit 2</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Unit 3 A really long one</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: My current 'solution' displays the menus vertically. Changing .dropdown to display:inline-block puts them side-by-side, but squashes the menu content. :/

Comment: You can try look at this navigation on Github for now, while I play with jsFiddle and your code above. https://github.com/MartinBlackburn/responsive-nav

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWsLJ/)

Using the `white-sapce: nowrap;` you can stop text wrapping onto different lines.

Comment: Wow! My first SO question answered so quickly and courteously! Thanks. So... for the sake of interest: what if I wanted each menu heading to become as wide as the dropdown it heads? Is that easier, or harder, than doing it this way?

Comment: That would be harder, as the dropdown (ul) is position: absolute; it doesn't affect the width of its parent element (div.title)